# memory efficient solution for similarity calculations between items - purchases data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, cosine-similarity

I'm working on product recommendations.

My dataset is as follow ( A sample, the full one is with more than **110 000** **rows** and more than **80000 unique product_id**):

```
          user_id                     product_id

0     0E3D17EA-BEEF-493                12909837
1     0FD6955D-484C-4FC8-8C3F          12732936
2     CC2877D0-A15C-4C0A               Gklb38
3     b5ad805c-f295-4852               12909841
4     0E3D17EA-BEEF-493                12645715
```

I want to calculate the **[cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)** between products based on purchased products per user.

**Why?** I need to have as a final result:

*the list of the 5 most similar products for each product_id*.

So, I thought the 1st thing that I need to do is to convert the dataframe into this format:

[image: crosstab pandas function result]

where I have one row per user_id and columns are product_ids. If a user bought product_id X then the correspondant row,column will contain the value 1, otherwise 0.

I did that using crosstab function of pandas dataframe.

```
crosstab_df = pd.crosstab(df.user_id, df.product_id).astype('bool').astype('int')
```

After that, I calculated the similarities between products.

```
def calculate_similarity(data_items):
"""Calculate the column-wise cosine similarity for a sparse
matrix. Return a new dataframe matrix with similarities.
"""
# create a scipy sparse matrix
data_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(data_items)
#pairwise similarities between all samples in data_sparse.transpose()
similarities = cosine_similarity(data_sparse.transpose())
#put the similarities between products in a dataframe
sim = pd.DataFrame(data=similarities, index= data_items.columns, columns= data_items.columns)
return sim

similarity_matrix = calculate_similarity(crosstab_df)
```

I know that this is not efficient, because crosstab doesn't perform well when there is many rows and many columns, which is a case that I have to handle. So, I thought about instead of using a Crosstab DataFrame, I have to use **scipy sparse matrix** as it makes calculations faster (similarity calculations, vectors normalisation) because the input will be a numpy array, not a dataframe.

However, I didn't know how to do it. I also need to keep track of each column to what product_id it corresponds, so that I can then get the most similar product_ids to each product_id.

I found in other questions answers that:

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

can be used, but in my case I think, I can use it only after applying crosstab.. while I want to get rid of crosstab step.

Also, people suggested using [scipy coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix), but I didn't understand how can I apply it in my case, for the results I want..

I'm looking for **a memory efficient** solution as the initial dataset can grow for thousand of lines and hundred thousand of product_id..

Comment: Looks like a good use case for scikit-learn. Specifically `OneHotEncoder` and `KDTree`, but I can't be sure without seeing a data sample.

Comment: isn't the screenshot of the dataframe a sample? I didn't know how to successfully apply sklearn `OneHotEncoder` for this case and I also thing it won't be possible, I remember I tried it once and run into memory error.